Derivation of brownian differential and negligible higher orders
While I have studied calculus and statistics separately, it is my first attempt unifying the two via stochastic calculus.
Background Reasoning
Given some function:
$$
f(t,B_t)
$$
Where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion process, I want to find an expression for the infinitesimal difference $df$.
From multivariate calculus, I am familiar with computing this via partial differentials. That is, I would write:
$$
df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
$$
In reading various lecture notes, I believe the source of my confusion is why, in the above example from multivariate calculus, terms of 2nd order, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}dx$, and above, do not feature.
Elaborating, I consider the differential of the stochastic function $f$:
$$
df(t,B_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t}dB_t
$$
Consider the second derivative, treating the variable $t$ as constant for now. I assume the Brownian motion begins at $B_{t=0}=0$. I perform a Taylor Expansion about the point $B_{t=0}=0$:
$$
df(B_t) = \frac{d}{dB_t}f(0)dB_t + \frac{d^2}{dB_t^2}f(0)dB_t^2 + O(dB_t^3)
$$
I am comfortable that the expected value of the squared difference between two Gaussian random variables is equal to the variance of the distributions. In the case of the Brownian motion in discussion, this gives:
$$
dB_t^2=dt
$$
So, I can see that the differential with respect to $B_t$ contributes a differential of $B_t$ and a differential of dt.
Putting this all together, I have:
$$
df(t,B_t) = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B_t^2} \right)dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial B_t}dB_t
$$
I am reasonably comfortable with the derivation above, however I feel some of the steps I take may not be clear. If anyone is able to highlight areas I may be glossing over, that would be appreciated.
Specifically, including the deterministic multivariate case, why do terms of higher order not feature in:
$$
df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
$$
I am inclined to think that, if I divide through by some infinitesimal $dx$, and then let $dx$ go to zero, all higher order terms vanish. However, I can't quite seem to make a connection I am happy with.
Specific Question
The difficulty I have is in reasoning why a differential $df$ is:
$$
df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
$$
and not
$$
df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}dx^2 + ... + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy^2 + ...
$$
What is the reasoning that sets all higher order terms to zero ?

Ito's formula

Thankyou for the comment @Snoop. The link you type seems not to work. Yes, it is Itos formula I am trying to derive.

The derivation you are attempting can be found here. You can find a rigorous argument in pretty much any serious stochastic analysis book.

Weird that links seem not to work. I am trying to link Wikipedia's entry.

You are glossing over a missing factor $\frac12$ in front of the 2nd derivatives term. Apart from that I don't see a lot of reasons to repeat what you can find in standard sources.

To your specific question: You are messing around with the notation thereby still not adding the factor $\frac12$ that I mentioned. If -as you say- you studied calculus you should have learned that: 1. we do not derive the chain rule from the Taylor series. 2. The latter involves differences $\Delta x,\Delta y$ and not differentials $dx,dx^2$ and so on.
